# Invalid Token in MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I am trying to delete duplicates in my MySql database keeping 1 row using the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql).

```
DELETE
  e1
FROM
  email e1,
  email e2
WHERE
  e1.email = e2.email AND e1.pnum > e2.pnum
```

But I keep getting an "Invalid Token" error with the DELETE alias.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

MYSQL VERSION

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.10 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I tried to make it a little more readable and forgot to change u1 over.

Comment: after editing to `u1` to `e1` in your IDE, does it still complain? asking that to make sure because of the image you linked.

Comment: Correct it still complains

Comment: What client are you using to connect to MySQL?  The syntax seems right, and the error does not look like a proper error in the usual style of MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table email
(   -- the columns here aren't great, but illustrative
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    email text not null,
    rcvDate datetime not null
);

-- truncate table email;
insert email(email,rcvDate) values
('this is an email','2015-12-01 08:00:01'),
('greetings email','2015-12-01 09:00:01'),
('this is an email','2015-12-01 10:00:01'),
('this is an email','2015-12-01 11:00:01'),
('yet another email','2015-12-01 12:00:01');

select * from email;
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
| id | email             | rcvDate             |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | this is an email  | 2015-12-01 08:00:01 |
|  2 | greetings email   | 2015-12-01 09:00:01 |
|  3 | this is an email  | 2015-12-01 10:00:01 |
|  4 | this is an email  | 2015-12-01 11:00:01 |
|  5 | yet another email | 2015-12-01 12:00:01 |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
```

### The delete query

```
delete from  email
where concat(email, id) not in 
(   select dummy 
    from
    (   select concat(email, max(id)) as dummy
        from email
        group by email
    ) xDerived
);
```

### Results

```
select * from email;
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
| id | email             | rcvDate             |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
|  2 | greetings email   | 2015-12-01 09:00:01 |
|  4 | this is an email  | 2015-12-01 11:00:01 |
|  5 | yet another email | 2015-12-01 12:00:01 |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Inspired from Martin Smith at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4606939/1816093

One could use `rcvDate` for the max instead.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for DELETE query requires nothing between DELETE and FROM.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Your query should be in this form

```
DELETE FROM email e1, email e2 WHERE e1.email = e2.email AND e1.pnum > e2.pnum
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'e1,
  emails e2
WHERE
  e1.email = e2.email AND e1.pnum > e2.pnum' at line 3

Comment: When you're deleting from a `JOIN`, you need to specify which table you want to delete from.